# Map an Array without using the last element of the Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list

Is it possible to map an `Array` without using the last element of the `Array` and without creating a new `Array` to map.

```
{array.map((arr, index) => {
        ...
    }
)}
```

So if the array was:

```
{ 'apple', 'bread', 'banana'}
```

Only `apple` and `bread` would be mapped.

Use case for this question is  more because I was just wondering if it is possible. I know that there are solutions with splice and creating new Array that would be shorter but I just thought that it might be possible to solve this without mutating or creating new `Array's`

Comment: map will always return the values equal to the length of the array . so if you have 8 items in the array then the resultant array created using map should have the length 8 as well . its good to filter the array and use map .

Comment: It's not possible since map returns 1:1 matching array.

Comment: What's the use-case? Because using `map()` there's no way to stop the iteration, and if you don't return anything from any Array-element then `undefined` will be returned. Also, your "array" seems to be a destructuring-assgnment to create an object.

Comment: Use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) like this `array.slice(0, -1).map(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

slice array before map ?

```
array.slice(0,-1).map((arr, index) => 
 ...
})
```

Comment: If this array is from the state or props then we should not be doing this as it might mutate them .

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I'm not sure if that meets the criteria of "*without creating a new Array*", since this modifies the original Array. But the question is ambiguous, and doesn't offer enough context to be sure that concerns are being addressed.

Comment: Indeed if you don't want to create an intermediate array it is better to check the index before returning the element

Comment: Like mentioned here before, this is a state `Array` and slice'ing did mutate it.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use reduce, to avoid undefined of Array.map(), and check the index

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const newArray = array.reduce((acc, next, index) => {
        if (index < array.length - 1) {
          return acc.concat(next)
        }
        return [...acc] }, [])
        
        console.log(newArray)
```